# Storing JsonObjects that depend on each other

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

I am confronted with the following problem:
I got a class "Plot" that stores a list of its purchase contracts (Class "PurchaseContract"). The Class PurchaseContract on the other hand stores the plot, that it is referencing. I need both objects to point to each other, so other classes can also access them (e.g. an owner, that stores his favorite plots and his signed contracts).
For serialization and deserialization I am using fasterxml for Java.

Lets say there is a Plot "ExamplePlot" that stores the PurchaseContract "ExampleContract 1".
Now when it comes to storing those objects in a .json file everything works as intended. But when loading them back into the program, either there will be an error as one object will always be unknown or there will be 2 objects created instead of 1.

I tried giving each object an id, then loading all objects and finally executing a method "loadDependencies" (that loads all dependencies based on the stored id) for each object, that implements the interface "PostDeserializationDependencies".
But somehow this does not seem to be the right or elegant way and to make matters worse it spoils every class that relies on such dependencies, as for every object that needs to be loaded after serialization a field is needed to store said object's id.

This issue has been bothering me in multiple projects for quite some time now. I'd appreciate it if someone had a more elegant way of solving this problem, maybe even taking use of functionality the fasterxml library has to offer.

Comment: Storing an ID and referencing by that ID is in fact the _only_ way to handle circular references. For example, this is what Java serialization does internally.

Comment: if I was to store a contract in both the plot class and the owner class, I will end up with 2 seperate objects, where only one object should be. This way I could not add them back into a list, that stores all contracts ever created, because I would add 2 objects meaning the same thing. Also I could'nt compare them using .equals().

Comment: You need to investigate exactly how Java serialization handles object IDs; you have the same problem.